# How would I get the output of a Start-AzAutomationJob after it is finished?

Tags: azure, error-handling, powershell-cmdlet, azure-runbook

I'm trying to do some error handling with a runbook. I'm running `Start-AzAutomationRunbook` and trying to get the status of that job and if that status is **'Failed'** then do something with that.

Currently, when I try to `Write-Output $runazurejob` I get the data, but the status is set to **'New'**. This is not very helpful.

I've tried using `-Wait` on the `Start-AzAutomationRunbook`, but if I try to write the output, I get nothing.

How do I get the output of a Azure automation runbook job AFTER it is finished running?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the output of a Azure Automation runbook job AFTER it is finished running with the help of Az PS cmdlet [Get-AzAutomationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjob).

Example 1: If the runbook is with below code

```
#The following lines create a warning message and then an error message that will suspend the runbook.
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Write-Warning -Message "This is a warning message."
Write-Error -Message "This is an error message that will stop the runbook because of the preference variable."
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfbju.png)

then as shown in below screenshot, you could get the output of a Azure Automation runbook job AFTER it is finished running with the help of Az PS cmdlet [Get-AzAutomationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjob)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9uNs.png)

Example 2: If the runbook is with below code

```
Write-Output "This is a output message"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqi2m.png)

then as shown in below screenshot, you could get the output of a Azure Automation runbook job AFTER it is finished running with the help of Az PS cmdlets [Get-AzAutomationJobOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjoboutput) and [Get-AzAutomationJobOutputRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjoboutputrecord)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTeN3.png)

All the above mentioned Az PS cmdlets are just part of Az.Automation PS module. Please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/?view=azps-6.3.0 article for full list of supported cmdlets.